# Credit Card Swipe Interference

Tags: interference

I am asking a question as a part of library maintenance for electrical equipment.  We have installed a POS machine with credit card swipe on the same outlet as a laser scanner (used to check in books).  Apparently, the POS gets a signal immediately that a swipe has occurred and failed before a swipe occurs.  If the laser scanner is plugged into a different outlet (we are using an extension cord), everything works.  Using extension cords in a commercial facility is prohibited, so does another outlet need to be added?  What could be causing the POS to get a swipe signal? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: POS = Point of sale, not the other thing...

Comment: correct, it is a Point of Sale unit that has a cash drawer and a screen to process payments.  There is also a credit card swiper attached to the device.

Comment: A thought comes to mind, are the two pieces of machinery still next to each other regardless of which outlets?  If you separated the two to put the laser scanner on a different outlet, then a lot of factors were also removed.

Comment: Funkyguy, if the laser scanner is moved farther away, but still plugged in the same outlet, the swipe fails.  If the laser scanner is close, but plugged into a different outlet, the swipe works and does not time out.

Comment: Alright, then I still stand by my answer

Comment: Hmm, depending on how far you are moving the scanner you may be having noise problems on the cable or just a wiring error.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting, it sounds like your laser scanner is causing noise on the power cable which then interferes with the POS machines operation.  This is probably due to a poorly designed power supply in either of the machines.

If you can't use just a different outlet, then it might be worth trying to put a ferrous nugget around the power cable of the POS machine before you spend the money to put in a new outlet.

A ferrous nugget serves to filter out noise on power cables and many products have them.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I will see if we can do this... might be a quick fix.

Comment: @MaribelCabreraIbrahim You may also be able to use a plug-in noise filter, such as http://www.homedepot.com/p/Smarthome-FilterLinc-10-Amp-Plug-In-Noise-Filter-1626-10/100396290 for example. I don't know what country you're in so you might have to find the correct product for your electrical system.